# Using Discord user ID to store data in .JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I feel like the title of this problem just made this whole thing even more confusing. But here is the long of it:

I have a bot that uses .JSON files to store information a user puts into it upon creation. However, to ensure that they are creating one, and only one, file, I have tied it to their unique ID. This ensures that even if a user changes nicknames, he can only create one file for himself. Of course, the .JSON file in the background, will be named '123456789.txt'.

This has been done successfully, but I want to add in bot commands that will allow OTHER users to obtain information stored in that user's file. So, for example: If Joe wants to see what Ned's favorite color is, he could use a simple command like:

```
!favcolor Ned
```

And the bot will fine Ned's .JSON file (123456789.txt), look for what value is stored under the key "color", and print out the results.

The problem isn't that I can't find people's user ID (`ctx.message.author.id`). The problem is that I don't know how to let someone else do such, as, as far as I can find out, there is no way to ensure that when someone precedes '!favcolor' with 'Ned', the bot will find 123456789.txt.

The only solution I can think of at the moment is to maintain a .JSON file at the moment of creation of a file that grabs the user's unique ID, and then pairs it with the name of the user. Something like:

```py
{
"Ned": "123456789"
"Joe": "234567891"
"Sam": "345678912"
}
```

And so on. Then it just looks at that JSON, and grabs the correct ID. Is this a good approach? Or am I missing something much easier that is already built into discord.py?

Comment: Would a Member converter suit your needs? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#converters

Answer (score 0):

Discord users are only uniquely identifiable by ID or username#discriminator.
You can easily get the ID from a User object, given that you're able to identify it from the user input in question.

A .JSON file with a .txt extension is contradictory, and you should be storing JSON data in JSON files rather than text files.

Also, I'd recommend using a database rather than JSON files, as there are lot of advantages to doing so and a lot of disadvantages to continuing to use JSON files.

Comment: Stick with ID since username#discriminator can change (either nitro or just changing your username). I agree on recommending database if the data can increase in scope, but if it's only to store simple things (like favourite colour), then using JSON is also fine.

Comment: Retrieving a user by username#discriminator is fine, as their ID will still be the same. As for using a database, it depends on how important the data is to them, and how much of it they have, but generally, you want to future-proof.

Comment: username#discriminator is not guaranteed to return the same user. For example, if my combination is Benjin#1234 and someone with Nitro takes the username#discriminator, then mine will be changed. Querying Benjin#1234 will result in the other account, not mine. Using ID does not cause this.

Comment: Nitro does not allow you to take someone else's discriminator. That's not how it works. You can only choose a free username#discriminator combination. Regardless, even if you changed your discriminator yourself, retrieving your user object by your new username#discriminator would result in a User object with the same ID. Your ID does not change. Like I said, username#discriminator uniquely identifies a user, and there is nothing wrong with using username#discriminator to retrieve the corresponding User object to get their ID.